# Call Standard edit task from Custom Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to call standard edit task action from a lightning component button? I actually want to remove "Mark as Complete" standard button on task record page. and i could not find a way so i am trying to replace standard compact layout with a custom lightning component. But i want to be able to invoke "Edit Task" standard action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to invoke the standard edit popup in lightning, You need to navigate users to below URL on button click:-

> /lightning/r/Task/record-id/edit

You can use [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) to navigate via lightning aura component.

Another option would be using [force:editRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:editRecord/documentation) to edit the record which invoke the standard edit record panel in Lightning.

```
editRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
         "recordId": component.get("v.contact.Id")
   });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!!!